# MS Access VBA lookup image file names from table, search for them and copy them

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using Access 2013.  I have a list of images in a table.  I then need to search through a set of folders (including sub folders), locate the images and copy them to a new directory.  The table that contains the image names does not reference the file path.

What is the best way to achieve this?  Is it possible to loop through the table and perform the search, or would I have break it down and manually locate each file and update a flag to say it exists, then go back and copy them?

Not sure how to do this but would appreciate any ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: File system objet + loop through the recordset.

Comment: ok, I will give it a go

Answer (score 1):

For some import programs I had to manipulate files, create copies etc. and I created some functions to help process, you might find some use in them:

To create folder from VBA:

```
Public Function folderCreate(filePath As String) As Boolean
    'define variables
    Dim fsoFold As Object

    'set file system object
    Set fsoFold = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Not fsoFold.folderExists(filePath) Then
        'check if folder exists
        fsoFold.CreateFolder (filePath)
    End If

    folderCreate = True

    Set fsoFold = Nothing

End Function
```

To check if folder exists:

```
Public Function folderExists(folderPath As String) As Boolean
    'define variables
    Dim fso As Object

    'set file system object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'check if file exists
    If fso.folderExists(folderPath) Then
        folderExists = True
    Else
        folderExists = False
    End If

    Set fso = Nothing

End Function
```

To check if file exists:

```
Public Function fileExists(filePath As String) As Boolean
     'define variables
     Dim fso As Object

    'set file system object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'check if file exists
    If fso.fileExists(filePath) Then
        fileExists = True
    Else
        fileExists = False
    End If

    Set fso = Nothing

End Function
```

Similar to this, use movefile to move it to new location.

```
fso.movefile strFullPath, strFullBackUp
```

**EDIT: Following sub will go through given folder and list all JPG images - this code is just example how to find files, folders and how to recursively go through them.**

```
Public Sub listImages(folderPath As String)

    'define variables
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFolders As Object
    Dim objF As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim objFiles As Object
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim myList As String

    'set file system object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'set folder object
    Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(folderPath)

    'set files
    Set objFiles = objFolder.files
    Set objFolders = objFolder.subfolders

    'list all images in folder
    For Each objFile In objFiles

        If Right(objFile.Name, 4) = ".jpg" Then
            strFileName = objFile.Name
            strFilePath = objFile.Path
            myList = myList & strFileName & " - " & strFilePath & vbNewLine
        End If

    Next

    'go through all subflders
    For Each objF In objFolders

        'call same procedure for each subfolder
        Call listImages(objF.Path)

     Next

     Debug.Print myList

     Set objFolder = Nothing
     set objFolders = Nothing
     Set objFile = Nothing
     set objF = Nothing
     Set fso = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Does the 'file Exists' function search for sub folders as well?  I would need to do this.

Comment: File exist is looking if file exist with full path provided. Like fileExists("c:\test\image.jpg") - will return true only if there is image.jpg in test folder on C drive.

Comment: I need to search for any subfolders in "c:\test\" as well.

Comment: Do you have just file name or you like to list all JPG files in folder and subfolders?

Comment: they need to lookup the image name from a table, but will also need to be wildcard search

Comment: I added code for sub that will look through folder and return file names and path for each jpg picture it finds and return it to debug windows. Code is just example how to use fso.

Comment: Ok ,this is nearly there but only returns the FIRST image from each folder, I need it to return every image - how do I do this?

Comment: Also the Public Function folderCreate does not work.  If I call it, pass the folder in " ", it just returns error 76 'path not found'.  If not found, shouldn't it be creating it?

Comment: For each loop above, if set correctly will check all files that have one of selected extensions. For folder create function you need to provide path - can't create folder without path. Also it will not create child folder unless parent folder does not exists.

Comment: How do I set the loop correctly though?  it only returns the first image from each folder

Comment: Can you post your For each loop? Usually you have For each object in objectList.... do this  ... next

Comment: I haven't changed it from the post above

Comment: I have temp folder with 3 images and 2 sub-folders, first one has 2 more images and last one has 1 image. Here is output: [link](http://oi66.tinypic.com/9j40tc.jpg) .

Comment: can it go more then 2 sub folders deep though?  I think that is the issue.