# MS Access VBA lookup images from folders

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using the below code from this page:

[MS Access VBA lookup image file names from table, search for them and copy them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41300598/ms-access-vba-lookup-image-file-names-from-table-search-for-them-and-copy-them)

```
Public Sub listImages(folderPath As String)

    'define variables
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFolders As Object
    Dim objF As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim objFiles As Object
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim myList As String

    'set file system object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'set folder object
    Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(folderPath)

    'set files
    Set objFiles = objFolder.files
    Set objFolders = objFolder.subfolders

    'list all images in folder
    For Each objFile In objFiles

        If Right(objFile.Name, 4) = ".jpg" Then
            strFileName = objFile.Name
            strFilePath = objFile.Path
            myList = myList & strFileName & " - " & strFilePath & vbNewLine
        End If

    Next

    'go through all subflders
    For Each objF In objFolders

        'call same procedure for each subfolder
        Call listImages(objF.Path)

     Next

     Debug.Print myList

     Set objFolder = Nothing
     set objFolders = Nothing
     Set objFile = Nothing
     set objF = Nothing
     Set fso = Nothing


End Sub
```

However, it only returns the first image from each folder and sub folder.  How do I modify it so it shows all images in each folder\subfolder?

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that every variable except `myList` is local to the `listImages` function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean and don't fully understand I'm afraid.

Comment: `myList` is a local variable within `listImages` so it gets start over every time you call the function. Remove `Dim myList As String` and add `Public myList As String` outside of any function. Then make sure you set `myList=""` before the very first time you call `listImages` OUTSIDE the `listImages` function.

Comment: Just checked your code, worked for me fine. myList declaration is OK if all you need - just Debug.Print text. If you need function, which returns the string with files, declare myList as `Static` and add resetting of myList for not recursive calls or use public variable as proposed above

Comment: I still cannot get this to work.  If I declare Public myList As Static then I receive the error "Expected: New or type name"